# An archery game

Tags: probability

Let's imagine a sport in which two archers shoot at the same time on two different targets, the speed of shooting is at the same rate for each archer. The targets are selected before each competition individually by each archer. These targets vary in size, color and number of points, needed to be scored for the win by hitting it; that's such a strange game. In order to win, the archer must hit the target required times before before a similar is done by the opponent. If such conditions hold for each archer at the same time then we have a draw.

The 1st archer chose the 1st target; it is necessary to hit the 1st target 10 times to win, the probability of hitting the 1st target by 1st archer is 75%.

The 2nd archer chose the 2nd target; it is necessary to hit the 2nd target 12 times to win, the probability of hitting the 2nd target by the 2nd archer is 86%.

What are the coefficients to win the game by the 1st archer, by the 2nd or to get a draw?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What is a *coefficient to win the game*? The probability of winning the game?

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 2):

Call player 1 $A$, and has a probability of winning $a = 0.75$

Call player 2 $B$, and has a probability of winning $b = 0.86$

Now, the recurrences for winning in exactly $n$ steps:

\begin{align*}
  P_A\left(n\right) &= \sum_{i=1}^{10} \left(1-a\right)a^{i-1}P\left(n-i\right) \\
  P_A\left(10\right) &= a^{10} \\
  P_A\left(k\right) &= a^{10}\left(1-a\right)\hspace{20pt}\text{for $k=11\ldots 20$}
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
  P_B\left(n\right) &= \sum_{i=1}^{12} \left(1-b\right)b^{i-1}P\left(n-i\right) \\
  P_B\left(12\right) &= b^{12} \\
  P_B\left(k\right) &= b^{12}\left(1-b\right)\hspace{20pt}\text{for $k=13\ldots 24$}
\end{align*}

Hence, the probability of a draw is:

\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{P}\left(\text{Draw}\right) &= \sum_{n=10}^{\infty} P_A\left(n\right)\cdot P_B\left(n\right) \\
  &\approx 0.0108907854748
\end{align*}

Probability that $A$ wins is:
\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{P}\left(A<B\right) &= \sum_{k=10}^{\infty} P_A\left(n=k\right)\cdot P_B\left(n>k\right) \\
  &\approx 0.328106229131 
\end{align*}

Probability that $B$ wins is:
\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{P}\left(A>B\right) &= 1- 0.328106229131  - 0.0108907854748 \\
  &= 0.6610029853942
\end{align*}

The probabilities $P_A(n)$ and $P_B(n)$ have the following probability generating functions, which can be obtained from a markov chain, or from the recurrences.
They were used for calculating the above probabilities:

\begin{align*}
  G_A\left(x\right) &= \frac{a^{10} x^{10}}{{\left(a^{10} - a^{9}\right)} x^{10} + {\left(a^{9} - a^{8}\right)} x^{9} + {\left(a^{8} - a^{7}\right)} x^{8} + {\left(a^{7} - a^{6}\right)} x^{7} + {\left(a^{6} - a^{5}\right)} x^{6} + {\left(a^{5} - a^{4}\right)} x^{5} + {\left(a^{4} - a^{3}\right)} x^{4} + {\left(a^{3} - a^{2}\right)} x^{3} + {\left(a^{2} - a\right)} x^{2} + {\left(a - 1\right)} x + 1} \\
  G_B\left(x\right) &= \frac{b^{12} x^{12}}{{\left(b^{12} - b^{11}\right)} x^{12} + {\left(b^{11} - b^{10}\right)} x^{11} + {\left(b^{10} - b^{9}\right)} x^{10} + {\left(b^{9} - b^{8}\right)} x^{9} + {\left(b^{8} - b^{7}\right)} x^{8} + {\left(b^{7} - b^{6}\right)} x^{7} + {\left(b^{6} - b^{5}\right)} x^{6} + {\left(b^{5} - b^{4}\right)} x^{5} + {\left(b^{4} - b^{3}\right)} x^{4} + {\left(b^{3} - b^{2}\right)} x^{3} + {\left(b^{2} - b\right)} x^{2} + {\left(b - 1\right)} x + 1}
\end{align*}

If you want an exact solution and have enough patience, proceed as described in the similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534800/probability-that-a-need-more-coin-tosses-to-get-two-consecutive-heads-than-b).

### **Update**

Alright, here are the exact values!

Building the simultaneous equations as described in that linked answer, we will end up with 120 equations of 120 variables.

This is the required equation:
$$
A_{m,n} = a\, b\, A_{m+1,n+1}+a\, (1-b)\, A_{m+1,0}+(1-a)\, b\, A_{0,n+1}+(1-a)\, (1-b)\, A_{0,0}
$$
and use suitable conditions for the $A$ and $B$ to get the simultaneous equations.

On solving, we end up with these fractions:

Probability that $A$ wins:

```
128661468699006334270970545935163402035818351279278563034680248131211951306420818408303815664073402597810233410628379856174473510026480769849512780888470516916707988073632462382065397204020546646154950516579486430667685760596413858936657826384695765120008305093793237448375317
/
392133575272137033562321922529480637556002210277004603721797902898819466151384497738806782625797036923472568273600896561549333417714595893979748161963175736246220352217612811269094471136286210626868629349810370977735607823040083223533835780920071901429274067796963981352729761
```

Probability that $B$ wins:

```
259201463927349435654857219669092667793013975916096275424383507240622048922732900261901499593234202578969685479739744275800172189637965378580954101270438987858519192089714696009199518112275578000642985768411378237000904554750834140057317845238200853885146949160477867482653211
/
392133575272137033562321922529480637556002210277004603721797902898819466151384497738806782625797036923472568273600896561549333417714595893979748161963175736246220352217612811269094471136286210626868629349810370977735607823040083223533835780920071901429274067796963981352729761
```

Probability of a draw:

```
4270642645781263636494156925224567727169883081629765262734147526985465922230779068601467368489431746692649383232772429574687718050149745549281279804266231470993172054265652877829555819990085980070693064819506310067017507692835224539860109297175282424118813542692876421701233
/
392133575272137033562321922529480637556002210277004603721797902898819466151384497738806782625797036923472568273600896561549333417714595893979748161963175736246220352217612811269094471136286210626868629349810370977735607823040083223533835780920071901429274067796963981352729761
```

### **Update 2**

I read the question again. It's not mentioned that they must be consecutive hits!

Anyway, the equation won't change much:

$$
A_{m,n} = a\, b\, A_{m+1,n+1}+a\, (1-b)\, A_{m+1,n}+(1-a)\, b\, A_{m,n+1}+(1-a)\, (1-b)\, A_{m,n}
$$

and set the boundary conditions.

Therefore, without the constraint of consecutive hits:

Probability that $A$ wins:

```
534150450266477653874216085760600428121292900457 / 992438238358118763882506280744260200076845920193
```

$\approx 0.538220344220283$

Probability that $B$ wins:

```
309351085995527832774459980818626475477199204593 / 992438238358118763882506280744260200076845920193
```

$\approx 0.311708148717965$

Probability of a draw:

```
148936702096113277233830214165033296478353815143 / 992438238358118763882506280744260200076845920193
```

$\approx 0.150071507061752$

### **Update 3**

We may also compute it from the summations, by fixing the last shot as a hit.
\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{P}\left(A<B\right) &= \sum_{k=10}^{\infty} P_A\left(n=k\right)\cdot P_B\left(n>k\right) \\
  &= \sum_{k=10}^{\infty} \binom{k-1}{9}a^{10}(1-a)^{k-10} \cdot \left(\sum_{i=k+1}^{\infty} \binom{i-1}{11} b^{12}(1-b)^{i-12}\right) \\
  &= \frac{534150450266477653874216085760600428121292900457}{992438238358118763882506280744260200076845920193}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{P}\left(A=B\right) &= \sum_{k=10}^{\infty} P_A\left(n=k\right)\cdot P_B\left(n=k\right) \\
  &= \sum_{k=10}^{\infty} \binom{k-1}{9}a^{10}(1-a)^{k-10} \cdot  \binom{k-1}{11} b^{12}(1-b)^{k-12} \\
  &= \frac{148936702096113277233830214165033296478353815143}{992438238358118763882506280744260200076845920193}
\end{align*}

Comment: I have been reading your solutions lately, and it is of high sophistication.  I tried to attempt this problem and am getting different results.  Could you comment where I am making a mistake.

Comment: Hi, I mostly tend to use generating functions for combinatoric problems as they can be easily manipulated with a CAS, they wouldn't be 'sophisticated' once we get used to it. To comment on your mistake, I didn't understand how you got those values. Each player shoots at the same time, so, for $n$ time units, they will each shoot $n$ arrows. If $A$ gets 10 consecutive hits first, $A$ wins, and similarly for the other cases. If we think in that manner, I believe I got the right answers, which also agree with simulations.

Comment: I wrote a function in Sage for calculating the above probabilities, where we can flexibly set the parameters like probability of hitting, number of hits to determine the winner etc., which is available [here (#17)](https://github.com/g-ar/sagecodes/blob/master/sagecode-3.py).

Comment: Should it be the opposite for the probabilities of A and B.  Draw seems to be straightforward.  I have used the negative binomial distribution to describe the probability of hitting the targets which is equivalent to your non-consecutive hits.  Besides the formulation is the same as yours.

Comment: I double-checked the probabilities before posting them, and believe to be correct. It feels a bit strange since the winning probability does not favor the same player for both the consective and non-consecutive hits. I still don't get it why our results differ.

Comment: Let me try to explain my logic and see where you or I go wrong.  Negative binomial essentially describes the probability that x number of failures occur before kth success and described by NB(x,k,p).  These failures could happen in non-consecutive ways and hence you have combination formula to fit these failures in a total trial of (x+k-1). Having given this definition, player A wins on the 10th success with p = .75 and player B wins on the 12th success with p = 0.86.  Both of them are independent.  (contd..)

Comment: Given this, with x1 = 0, player A wins in the first 10 throws.  Player B will draw with x2 = 0 and loose when x2>=1.  If player A has a failure, x1 = 1, Player A wins in 11 throws and Player B will draw with x2 = 1 and will loose when X2>=2.  Keeps going until at all stages player A will capture the winning circumstances.  For player B to win the opposite is true. When both players have the same failures before they hit the successful number of times, then they draw.  (Contd...)

Comment: Since the problem has not specified any number of finite rounds (cut-off) you run the cut-off to infinity and thus the probability will be equal to one.  Now tell me where is the mistake in the logic?

Comment: @satishramanathan : I have updated my answer. (Is that a negative binomial distribution?)

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

The answer assumes that player A has 2 failures of advantage when it is still considered a draw. The probabilities that you get at the bottom line is the probability that A wins and B wins and they draw.

[image]